# Privacy policy publish

Tags: android, google-play, privacy-policy

I created an android application which with ability to sign in with Googpe Play Services and get leaderboard data of player for my game. Now Google said that I must provide privacy policy.
There is problem: privacy policy must be placed in the web site, but I have no site and also I have no skills to create site. I am not web-developer, I am Android developer.
There is services to place my privacy policy in the web?

Comment: https://sites.google.com/new

Comment: Read https://developers.google.com/actions/policies/privacy-policy-guide

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a programming question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion the problem is that you need to add a **Privacy Policy** to your app and to your Console.

To do this you need to:

1. create Privacy Policy

Easy way to do this is with the [Privacy Policy Generator](https://app-privacy-policy-generator.firebaseapp.com/)

2. Add it to your app and Console

   Google Console -> your app -> store presence -> store listing -> Privacy Policy.
3. Then you need to generate .apk file (Android Studio -> Build > Build > Generate Signed Bundle/APK) with a **higher Version code** then before.
4. Add another release to your app – don’t create another app with the same package name.

Console -> your app -> Release management -> App releases

5. Wait

Usually it takes a few hours for google to unlock the app.

Answer (score 0):

I tried google sites and it did not let me use the uri in the interface to set up the privacy policy.  I was able to use [wix][1]

[1]: https://wix.com with good results. This is not a plug for them though...

Comment: Thank you for answer, but wix is overhead. I tried public url of some google doc, where I put policy. And it worked< application was approved.